# How can I send data to a web server and read that by sim800 or sim900?

Tags: http, webserver, gprs, sim900, sim800

I've heard that there are two methods to do that, GET and POST and I know the differences like in GET method we send data in URL and in POST method we do that in some rules. But I don't know how to do that with sim800 or sim900 and how to configure my module.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to initialize the SIMCOM module:

Initialization

1. Set context type: AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"\r\n
2. Set APN: AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","YourAPN"\r\n
3. Open bearer: AT+SAPBR=1,1\r\n
4. Query bearer: AT+SAPBR=2,1\r\n
5. Enable HTTP functions: AT+HTTPINIT\r\n
6. Set bearer profile identifier: AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1\r\n
7. Set the URL: AT+HTTPPARA="URL","YourURL"\r\n
8. Set Content-Type field in the HTTP header: AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"\r\n

After the SIMCOM module has been initialized you can POST or GET:

For a POST request

1. Set the JSON string to be sent: AT+HTTPDATA=StringLength,20000\r\nYourJSONString
2. HTTP POST: AT+HTTPACTION=1\r\n

For a GET request

1. HTTP GET: AT+HTTPACTION=0\r\n